# Ajax cart pro extension conflicts in magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I installed ajax cart pro into my magento 1.9 and  I am using sm-ballishop theme. If I enable ajax cart pro extension I am getting conflicts in my theme. I am unable to find what exactly is going wrong as I am new to magento. I got the following screenshot: [Click to view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKgqB.png)
I am getting errors like this:
[Click to view errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoSJg.png). The path should be like  http://testshop.wellplannedgal.com/js/prototype/validation.js but it is taking  http://testshop.wellplannedgal.com/var/www/html/shoptest.wellplannedgal.com/js/prototype/validation.js

Comment: There are php classes being overwritten by your modules. Basicly this means you must disable these modules but this might affect your magentos installation functionality.

Comment: I know the module is causing the issue, but I don't know where exactly the issue is and I want this module to be there, at the same time without conflicts. How can I do this ?